# Detect If Scanner Doesn't Have Next

Tags: java, file-io, java.util.scanner

I have the following file, which I'm using as a test:

> id=1392
>   name=Nathan
>   gender=male
>   testempty=
>   testempty2=
>   zip=11111

I'm looping lines and calling the function `processLine(String line)` on them to process `Strings`:

```
private String processLine(String line) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(line);
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    scanner.useDelimiter("=");

    if (scanner.hasNext()) {
        result.append(scanner.next());
        result.append(" , ");
        result.append(scanner.next());
        result.append(" , ");
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

But how I can detect if there is no next (like on `testempty`) and do a `result.append("empty , ")`?

Comment: If I were you, I'd read the file line by line, and for each line use `line.split('\\s*=\\s*', 2)` to get the tokens.

Comment: I think you could use java.util.Properties to parse your file.

Comment: @JackEdmonds I'm trying to convert the code so I can use `java.util.Properties` right now, but how can I get the list of properties and convert them into a `String[]`?

Comment: You can get a `Set` of the properties with java.util.Properties.stringPropertyNames (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#stringPropertyNames%28%29).  Then it's pretty easy to convert that to an array assuming you don't care about the order.

Comment: @JackEdmonds If I try this `Set set = prop.stringPropertiesName();` Eclipse says: `The method stringPropertiesName() is undefined for the type Properties`

Comment: Looks like that method was added in 1.6. However, Properties looks like it extends Hashtable so you could try `keySet()`.

Answer (score 1):

*(I think this is what you are asking for)*

Change lines:

```
result.append(scanner.next());
```

to:

```
result.append(scanner.hasNext() ? scanner.next() : "empty");
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your method. Append "," before appending value if the result is not empty yet:

```
if (scanner.hasNext()) {
    if (!result.isEmpty()) {
     result.append(" , ");
    }
    result.append(scanner.next());
    result.append(" , ");
    result.append(scanner.next());
}
```